# JavaScript Custom Data Array to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have tried to write an utility function that can convert my custom data (data Sencha Touch stores use) to JSON format and I am almost done but it fails with complex data coming from twitter API but works fine with simple type of data.

**Custom Data**

```
var items = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   var item = {};

   var data = {};
   data.prop1 = "123456789";
   data.prop2 = "Some Name";
   data.prop3 = "Some Date and Time";

   item.data = data;

   items.push(item);
}
```

Now above data can be accessed in a loop and can be converted to JSON with following function.

```
function toJSON(items) {
    var jsonString = "[";

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];

        jsonString += "{";

        for (var propertyName in item.data) {
            jsonString += '"' + propertyName + '":' + '"' + item.data[propertyName] + '",';
        }

        if (jsonString.substr(jsonString.length - 1, 1) === ",") {
            jsonString = jsonString.substr(0, jsonString.length - 1);
        }

        jsonString += "},";
    }

    if (jsonString.substr(jsonString.length - 1, 1) === ",") {
        jsonString = jsonString.substr(0, jsonString.length - 1);
    }

    jsonString += "]";

    return jsonString;
}
```

The question is if I am doing the encoding thing right?

You can see these fiddle to get real time experience http://jsfiddle.net/WUMTF/ and http://senchafiddle.com/#gxtZ9

Comment: Why don't you use [JSON.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)?

Comment: Are you purposely leaving the data property out of your output? Your output is identical to what `JSON.stringify` (built into modern browsers) gives you except for the lack of the `data` attribute in each item. If you purposely are leaving it out, I'd argue it's easier to massage the data then use `JSON.stringify` or one of many JSON JS libs out there.

Comment: I don't have control over the data and it would always be only a level deep.

Comment: You have control over the data, if nothing else you can clone it and the perform surgery on the clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you don't just use the native [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON) method, or the (wrapped) versions provided by your favorite JavaScript / AJAX library?  They will be more robust, tested, secure, and better performing.  (Most of the library versions will simply call the browser's native methods if available.)

Your `toJSON` implementation may be working for your simple test data, but is failing for more complex types of data for many reasons, but most probably most significantly, because it fails to account for any type of nesting.  It assumes that the top level is always an array, and that each element in the array only has properties one level deep.  Take a look at https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json.js .  This is the implementation provided by Douglas Crockford, the "father" of JSON.  Pretty much everything shown there is required for a valid implementation.  Unfortunately, the odds are against you if you think that you can easily and simply recreate this in a short amount of time (short of copy and paste).

Comment: You would have seen the response in the jsfiddle so this is the response I am interested in getting when it encodes. JSON would not encode in that response right?

Comment: I don't have control over custom data which I have simulated above.

Comment: @UmairAshraf - see Matt's comment to your question (above).  Additionally, see my fork of your jsFiddle that proves this:  http://jsfiddle.net/rUQ78/1/.  +1 with Matt's suggestion - either massage either the input data, or even the output after calling JSON.stringify - but don't try to re-create the JSON conversions on your own unless you have a proven need (very unlikely).

Comment: Assuming my data would always have data property in it and only a level deep then this is the correct implementation right? It won't break with special characters.

Comment: @UmairAshraf - That's not even true.  Dates won't convert properly to spec, and no, you're missing any proper special character handling.  A tab character, for example, currently fails to convert to `\t`. Worse, an embedded quotation (`"`) fails to be encoded, causing the JSON String to be completely invalid.  There are still other issues that probably exist and would need to be tested for.  I strongly urge you to just use the native implementation!

Comment: I have even tried that. JSON.stringify returns this error "Converting circular structure to JSON".

Comment: I think I have fixed it. What I am doing is, convert this type of array to JSON friendly array and then use JSON.stringify. Cheers!